# reading name of json using groovy

Tags: json, groovy, xmlslurper, jsonslurper

I have the below JSON structure  and I am trying to retrieve the name order/sale/Cancel to a string variable in groovy

```
{"Transaction" : {"Order" : { ......
{"Transaction" : {"Sale" : { ......
{"Transaction" : {"Cancel" : { ......
```

I was able to get to this point, reading the JSON using JSON slurper with some research but not sure how to get read the name.. most of the articles I have seen the point to reading the values and not the name.

```
final BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, 'UTF-8'))
Object result = jsonSlurper.parse(inReader)
```

I have converted from XML to JSON so if this can be done using either XML or JSON would help.

Answer (score 2):

Correct would be to use :

```
def json = '{"Transaction" : {"Order" : "result"} }'

def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(json)

assert 'Order' == result.Transaction.keySet().first()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have JSON in String you don't need to create `BufferedReader`, just use `parseText`. After you parse JSON you can just access it by traversing properties.

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(inputStream.text)​;

result.Transaction.Order​ //result
```

Comment: json is not in string, so have to use the bufferedReader

Comment: You can use `getText()` method on inputStream to get it as String. Edited my answer.